# php and html form with file upload not working

Tags: php, html

```
<form action="mail/career-mail.php" id="work-form" method="post">
     <div class="form-group text-center heading">
        <h2>Work With Us</h2>
     </div>

     <div class="form-group"> 
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Name" required="required">
     </div>

     <div class="form-group"> 
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="contact" placeholder="Contact Number" required="">
     </div>

     <div class="form-group"> 
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email" required="">
     </div>

     <div class="form-group"> 
         <select class="form-control" id="designation" name="designation"> 
         <option value="none">Select Designation</option> 
            <option value="BDM">BDM</option> 
            <option value="BDE">BDE</option> 
            <option value="Operations Manager">Operations Manager</option> 
            <option value="Research Analyst (Voice and/or Data)">Research Analyst (Voice and/or Data)</option> 
            <option value="Team Lead">Team Lead</option> 
            <option value="Quality Analyst">Quality Analyst</option> 
            <option value="MIS">MIS</option> 
            <option value="Human Resource (Generalist)">Human Resource (Generalist)</option> 
            <option value="others">Others</option>
         </select>
     </div>

     <div class="form-group otherblock"> 
        <textarea name="others" name="others" placeholder="Other"></textarea>
     </div> 

     <div class="form-group file-upload"> 
        <label>Upload Resume</label>  
             <input type="file" id="field40707" name="field40707">  
        <p>limit to 1 mb. File types, .doc, .docx, .pdf</p>                 
     </div>

     <div class="form-group">  
        <select class="form-control"> 
           <option value="none">How did you hear about us?</option> 
           <option value="Intranet">Intranet</option> 
           <option value="LinkedIn">LinkedIn</option> 
           <option value="via Job website">Via Job Website</option>   
        </select>                         
     </div>

     <div class="form-group radio-wrap"> 
        <label>Do you authorize a Representative from HQL Solutions to contact you.</label>               
        <div class="inline-block"> 
           <input type="radio" name="referance" value="yes" checked=""> Yes<br>
        </div> 
        <div class="inline-block"> 
           <input type="radio" name="referance" value="no"> No<br>
        </div>  
     </div> 

     <div class="form-group text-center mr-b-0">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-orange">Submit</button>
     </div>
  </form> <!-- work-form --> 

<?php
if($_POST){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $contact = $_POST['contact'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $designation = $_POST['designation'];
    $others = $_POST['others'];
    $field40707 = $_POST['field40707'];
    $referance = $_POST['referance'];   

    // Always set content-type when sending HTML email
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

    // More headers
    $headers .= 'From: noreply@hqlsolutions.com' . "\r\n";

    $to  = "niranjan.pawar2@gmail.com" ;

    $subject = "Careers form ";  

    $message .= " Name :". $name."\r\n";
    $message .= " Contact :". $contact."\r\n";
    $message .= " Email :". $email."\r\n";
    $message .= " Designation :". $designation."\r\n";
    $message .= " Others :". $others."\r\n"; 
    $message .= " field40707 :". $field40707."\r\n";
    $message .= " Referance :". $referance."\r\n";

    var_dump($name);
    var_dump($contact);
    var_dump($email);
    var_dump($designation);
    var_dump($others);
    var_dump($field40707);
    var_dump($referance);

    //get file details we need
    $file_tmp_name    = $_FILES['resume']['tmp_name'];
    $file_name        = $_FILES['resume']['name'];
    $file_size        = $_FILES['resume']['size'];
    $file_type        = $_FILES['resume']['type'];
    $file_error       = $_FILES['resume']['error'];

    $user_email = filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

    if($file_error>0)
    {
        die('upload error');
    }
    //read from the uploaded file & base64_encode content for the mail
    $handle = fopen($file_tmp_name, "r");
    $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
    fclose($handle);
    $encoded_content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));

    $boundary = md5("sanwebe");
    //header
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "From:".$from_email."\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$user_email."" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary = $boundary\r\n\r\n";

    //plain text
    $body = "--$boundary\r\n";
    $body .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
    $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n";
    $body .= chunk_split(base64_encode($message));

    //attachment
    $body .= "--$boundary\r\n";
    $body .="Content-Type: $file_type; name=\"$file_name\"\r\n";
    $body .="Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file_name\"\r\n";
    $body .="Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
    $body .="X-Attachment-Id: ".rand(1000,99999)."\r\n\r\n";
    $body .= $encoded_content;

    // if(mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers)){
    // echo "mail sent";  
    // else{
    // echo "Try agin later";   
    // };

    if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)){
        echo "mail sent";   
    }
    else{
        echo "not sent";
        phpinfo();
    };
}
?>
```

There are two blocks of code, one is for html and 2nd is for php mail function. When I click on submit expected result needs to get all the form-values in mail, but output comes with empty mail.

Can you please help because when I dump variable it shows the value  but in mail it comes empty.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: A general remark: stop keeping the html markup and the code to process the form submission in the same file. I know that most beginners tutorials start that way, but it is just plain stupid. Keep separate things separate.

Comment: About the specific issue: it is impossible for us to spot a potential issue in this wall of code. Please learn how to post a minimal verifiable example of your issue.

Comment: `$message` variable is not declared but that might not create issue, you can dump the `$message` variable after assigning value to it.

Comment: One hint: have a try checking the actual content of the message you send out (receive), _not_ what some email client displays. Good email clients offer an option to access the message "source". That helps in tackling down such issues.

Comment: And another general question: why would one want to create a complex multi part mime message with annoying html part of all you place inside is plain text?

Comment: Action url is `mail/career-mail.php` but you `POST` on the same page.. interesting!

Comment: @all there are different page one for html and 2 for mail/career-mail.php,

Comment: Can any one help me with file upload php function, because once i remove file upload function it works all values are getting in mail except file value

Comment: For the sake of simplicity, wht not just use the [PHPmailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) class.

Answer (score 0):

when you are working with files in a form you have include

```
<form action="mail/career-mail.php" enctype='multipart/form-data' id="work-form" method="post">

</form>
```